# Random number generator collision

Tags: c#

I implemented a method which generates automaric letters and numbers in random way.

```
public static string GenerateRandomNumber()
{
    using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        var bytes = new byte[8];

        rng.GetBytes(bytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

What are the probabilities that this randomNumberGenerator class would generate collision?

Comment: Obviously it will generate collision at some point if you call it more than once... But impossible to give correct answer without knowing quality of your random number generator and number of results you want.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of `RandomNumberGenerator`, but right now, I'm thinking the probability of a collision is 100%, since you are instantiating a new instance with each call. If you were using System.Random, that would be the case... [try it out on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CojGnJ).

```
public class Program
{
    public static string RandomNumber()
    {
        var rng = new System.Random();
        var bytes = new byte[8];

        rng.NextBytes(bytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber());
        Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber());
    }
}
```

Output (oops!):

```
EgNMBvntr1w=
EgNMBvntr1w=
```

My suggestion would be to instantiate only one instance of `RandomNumberGenerator` and hold it in a static variable throughout the lifespan of your program. If you do it that way, the odds will be more like 1 in 2^64.

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly rng = new System.Random();

    public static string RandomNumber()
    {
        var bytes = new byte[8];

        rng.NextBytes(bytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber());
        Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber());
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify i'm using Random Number Generator which belongs System.Security.Criptography.Algorithms namespace c# language and not Sytem.Random()